# Android Bluetooth Audio input samples

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-audiomanager, android-mediarecorder

Is it possible to pair Bluetooth microphone with Android device and receive audio samples in real time and record them to an audio file? I looked at lot of posts and found no conclusive answer if it is possible or not.